# With most recent 0.6.0 Chrome Mobile App update --release splits APK into Armv7 and x86? Way to merge into one?

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime, cordova-chrome-app

before this latest update I was creating a single APK file with this terminal command:

```
./platforms/android/cordova/build --release
```

But now when I run it it creates two different APK files, an `armv7` and `x86` apk. I believe this has something to do with google chrome apps switching to Crosswalk version 11 perhaps? I'm not entirely sure.

Is there any way to err.. recombine them? Or maybe was I only making one version this whole time? Before the output file would be:

```
android-release-unsigned.apk
```

now I have these:

```
android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk
android-x86-release-unsigned.apk
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can submit multiple apk for a single app, check [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/submitting-multiple-crosswalk-apk-to-google-play-store) and [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/9a/72/Intel_Walkthrough_GP-Multiple_APK_Submissions.pdf) for the steps by step.

Comment: Is it possible to drop them on an android device for testing ? I Tried with both but the apk couldn't install.